# Grouping data from JSON and display on a list

Tags: java, json, grouping

I have a JSON data like this:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "kodeHp": "C-1",
      "firstName": "iman",
      "lastName": "firmansyah",
      "email": "ggag@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "kodeHp": "C-2",
      "firstName": "dini",
      "lastName": "yyyy",
      "email": "ggag@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "kodeHp": "C-1",
      "firstName": "tanu",
      "lastName": "xxxxx",
      "email": "bb@gmail.com"
    },
```

I want to display the "firstName" on a list but sorted by the "kodeHp" object. So my list gonna looks like this:

```
{
iman: C1
tanu: C1
dini: C2
}
```

This is what I have tried:

```
private String parseItems(String jsonResponse) {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
            JSONArray jArray = jObj.getJSONArray("items"); //edited on gscript

            for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jo = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String kodeHp = jo.getString("kodeHp");
                String firstName = jo.getString("firstName");
                String lastName = jo.getString("lastName");
                String email = jo.getString("email");

                HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<>();
                if (!item.containsKey(kodeHp)){
                    item.get(kodeHp);
                }
                item.put("firstName", firstName);
                item.put("lastName", lastName);
                item.put("email",email);
                item.put("kodeHp", kodeHp);
                list.add(item);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e){

        }
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.item_list_row,
                new String[]{"firstName", "kodeHp"}, new int[] {R.id.TvFirstName,R.id.TvKodeHp});

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        loading.dismiss();
        return jsonResponse;
    }
```

It works to display my JSON data but not yet sorted like I want. Any suggestion?

Comment: you **always** create a new HashMap for `item`, therefore `item.containsKey(kodeHp)` can never be true in the very next line. Also, it doesn't make sense to try to get the value that you just confirmed as absent.

Comment: what should it be? because if I remove those line my app ended up with crash

Comment: well, for a start you can remove the 3 lines after creating the HashMap, as they do nothing. ([`HashMap.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html#get(java.lang.Object)) just returns `null` when the key is not found.

Comment: Why don't you create objects from the json string and then sort them? It will be more cleaner in my opinion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort your list, you can use [`List.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)) with an appropriate `Comparator`, for example using [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function)):

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(map -> map.get("kodeHp")));
```

Note that this will sort alphabetically by the values of `"kodeHp"`. Also note that you will have to add handling for `null` values if they are possible in you input data.

---

In case you need a pre-Java8 solution, e.g. for old Android versions, you'll have to create an old-fashioned anonymous class instead, for example:

```
list.sort(new Comparator<Map<String,String>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Map<String,String> o1, Map<String,String> o2) {
        return o1.get("kodeHp").compareTo(o2.get("kodeHp"));
    }
});
```

Comment: anyway how to use it without lambda expression? I have tried in 2 device, the first one with API level 23 and the second one with API level 29. It doesn't work on API level 23, after looking for some solutions it just because the lambda expression couldn't be use with API <24

Comment: @SeptiaDiniRahayu added a version doing this the way we did in the good old days when "everything" was an Object ;-)